# How to make table header always on top?

Tags: css, vue.js, element-ui

I am trying to make table header always on top in Element UI. I have tried solutions from classic css like: `position: stiky;` for `th` but it does not work for Element UI. The table is continue to scroll with it's header.

Here is my code https://jsfiddle.net/wb06nm51/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 ways to achieve this.

First the way specified by element-ui, and specify the height of the table on el-table: https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/table#table-with-fixed-header

Second is to use css as you did, but you have take into account that element-ui creates 2 tables 1 for the header and 1 for the body. the correct css that has to be applies is the following:

```
.el-table__header-wrapper {
  z-index: 100;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}

// Neede to show the first row in the table
.el-table__body-wrapper {
   margin-top: 50px;
}
```

To make it work in your fiddle make sure you also import the right css:

```
@import url("//unpkg.com/element-ui@2.13.0/lib/theme-chalk/index.css");
```