# Sticky Table Header With CSS For Element-UI Component

Tags: css, html-table, css-position, sticky, element-ui

In my code I used element-ui table (https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/table) component. It works nice but I want to customize the table header as sticky.

It provides it with max-height/height content like: https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/table#table-with-fixed-columns-and-header

But I want to use it like: https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/PrJdxb

In CSS, there are some tricks about it, like:

```
th {
  background: white;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  ...
}
```

I wonder in here, how can I implement it? Is there any suggestion?

My Case is:

```
<div css="first-section">
  ...
</div>
<div css="second-section">
  ...
</div>
<el-table>
  ...
</el-table>
```

Example: https://codepen.io/senolatac/pen/qBdGvRy

To see it on full-screen mode: https://codepen.io/senolatac/full/qBdGvRy

Comment: You looking this in html? the codepen works in that case, what you need then?

Comment: There are pre-components before table; like; `<div></div><div></div>...<el-table></el-table>` so in this case sticky-table works only in itself.

Comment: I don't see any components in the codepen you shared, can you let us know what is it needed and why can 't you use the codepen code?

Comment: You can check here: https://codepen.io/senolatac/pen/qBdGvRy

Comment: Ok, but the codepen you shared now has sticky header so you want that header to replaced with normal html table ? ot `el-table`?

Comment: I should use el-table. In here, I wonder how I can customize el-table.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210920/discussion-between-manjuboyz-and-sha).

Comment: Is this where you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60703429/how-to-make-table-header-always-on-top/60736178#60736178

Comment: @dreijntjens, no; this solution assumes only a table in content. But my content contains other components also.

Answer (score 0):

This package simulate `position: sticky` behavior.

Internally it use `position: relative` and compute `top` dynamically.

Example your scenario: https://codepen.io/iattempt/pen/eYdpoMV
(`z-index: 4` is used to cover fixed table column.)

You can check here for more usage: [element-ui-sticky-table example on CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/element-ui-sticky-table-fsuwj?file=/src/App.vue)

Comment: Please explain where the link goes to and how it relates to the question.

Comment: @M-Chen-3 That would not be enough to change a link-only answer to an accepted answer on StackOverflow. Luckily the author also added a minimum of explaining *how* it works. (Not only where and what is linked.)